# How to modify a low level driver in order to make it AUTOSAR compliant?

Tags: embedded, driver, autosar

I wrote a low level driver for a CAN module,and now I have to modify it in order to make it AUTOSAR compliant. I've looked through the layered software architecture, SWS and SRS CAN documents available on [autosar.org](https://www.autosar.org/) but the whole thing is over my head.
I don't know how to approach this problem. What do you think would be a good starting point / strategy?

I should mention that I am new to this field. I've had this job for 4 months and in college I studied electronics engineering. Also, at my job I am the only one in this department. I get directions from time to time from a superior, so I don't really have someone who can help me when I get stuck.

Comment: It is possible given more focus that your question could be answered by someone who is not necessarily an AUTOSAR expert, and that in turn would widen your audience (bu you doing a little work).  For example you have linked to the AUTOSAR.org homepage rather than to the documents or standards you are referring to.  When you say "low-level driver" what does that cover (in terms of OSI layers and application interface for example) - because it could mean any thing.  Adding your existing driver API to the question might help.

Comment: Also what version of AUTOSAR?  The current R19-11 release CAN driver specification is https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/19-11/AUTOSAR_SWS_CANDriver.pdf

Comment: It seems that you need to implement the functions declared in Can.h and specified in section 8.3.  I am no expert in AUTOSAR, but I have experience of wading through specifications, and that is where I'd start.

Answer (score 0):

AUTOSAR specification includes *coding guidelines* (likewise as i.e. MISRA-C, see i.e. https://blog.parasoft.com/breaking-down-the-autosar-coding-guidelines-for-adaptive-autosar) that have to be obeyed In MISRA-C i.e. some pointer operations are considered as critical for security and so are not allowed and also  recursions are not allowed because the limited control of the recursion depth (stack smashing,...)